# "User is not authenticated" error verifying authentication code after updating the e-mail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

After I submit the verification code sent to the user's email after a email update, when I try to verify with verifyAttribute, it throws the following error: "User is not authenticated"

getUser returns a CognitoUser.

```
onSubmitEmailConfirmation = async (values) => {
    const { code, newEmail, password } = this.state;
    const { first_name, last_name, email } = this.props.data;
      getSession()
        .then(({ user, email }) => {
          authenticate(email, password).then(() => {
            getUser(email).verifyAttribute("email", code, {
              onSuccess: () => {
                this.props.updateUserData({
                  email: newEmail,
                  first_name: first_name,
                  last_name: last_name
                });
                this.updateNotificationMessages(
                  "Email verified with success!",
                  newEmail
                );
                this.openNotificationWithIcon("success");
              },
              onFailure: (err) => {
                this.updateNotificationMessages(
                  "There was a error confirming your email",
                  err.message
                );
                this.openNotificationWithIcon("error");
              }
            });
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          this.updateNotificationMessages(
          "There was a error confirming your email",
          err.message
        );
          this.openNotificationWithIcon("error");
        });
  };
```